# Чем отличается двоичный файл от обычного

Tags: c

Как возможно сделать обычный файл двоичным, чтобы уже в дальнейшем в программе  работать с двоичным файлом и использовать соответствующие  функции в программе.
Еще один вопрос: что такое размер текстового блока , и что может значить "размер кодируемого блока":8,12,16,24,32,48,64 разряда ?

Comment: Двоичный файл ничем не отличается от обычного, потому что и тот и другой хранят байты

Comment: То есть , если программа запишет двоичный файл, я не увижу нулей и единиц

Comment: Если программа запишет нули и единицы и вы его откроете в программе, интерпретирующей файл как текст - увидите.

Comment: Что вы увидиье в файле зависит только от вас, т.е. от тех средств, котопыми вы будете просматривать этот файл. Включите ружим "нулей и единиц" - увидите нули и единицы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну очевидно же, что он спрашивает про режимы открытия файлов. И, вообще-то, они различаются.

Comment: @AnT, то же самое.

Answer (score 3):

Любой файл состоит из байт (а байты из бит). В этом смысле любой файл - двоичный. Другое дело, что некоторые файлы состоят из байт, которые могут быть представлены символами (текстом) - см. [Набор символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) в Википедии.

Как работать с файлом как с двоичным - открыть его в соответствующем режиме, например `'rb'` для [`fopen`](http://cppstudio.com/post/1253/). И работать с ним с помощью соответствущих функций (`fread`, `fwrite`).

Размер блока - это может быть например размер блоков, которыми читаются данные из файла, например функцией [`fread`](http://cppstudio.com/post/1641/). А может быть что-то другое - уточняйте у того, кто давал задание.

Comment: И ни слова про текстовый режим...

Answer (score 3):

При открытии файла в двоичном режиме все данные в него пишутся в неизменном виде.

При открытии файла в текстовом режиме есть зависящая от операционной системы обработка символов перевода строки. Например, в Windows при записи `\n` реально будет записываться два символа `\r\n`, аналогично при чтении эти 2 символа будут превращаться в один.

Answer (score 2):

Если под текстовым файлом вы имеете в виду файл, в котором, скажем, элементы некоторого  массива типа `int` записаны в виде символов `1`, `223` `-54`  и т.п. (и вы их можете увидеть в обычном текстовом редакторе),
то тогда соответствующим ему двоичным файлом будет "слепок памяти" того же массива, записанный на диск (и если посмотреть на него в редакторе, то увидим сплошные "кракозябры").

Очевидно, чтобы сделать двоичный файл надо писать в него содержимое переменных программы  функцией [fwrite](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite).