# Перевод картинки расширения bmp в двоичный код

Tags: c, bmp, форматы-файлов

Возможно ли сразу перевести картинку, сохраненную в формате bmp c глубиной цвета 24 бит в двоичный код. И потом после некоторых манипуляций с этим двоичным кодом , вернуть обратно изображение. Возможно ли такое на Си ?

UPD
я пытался считывать в лоб (то есть открыл в HEX редакторе , посмотрел на сигнатуру BM , что за ASCII символы аналогичные 16-ричным стоят. Их и считывал в массив , чтобы потом в 2 код перевести. Но проблема : сигнатура BM не считывается корректно ,- завершающие нули считываются по середине(это я про сигнатуру) , а без неё не получится корректно вернуть обратно картинку )

Считаю  теперь с двоичного

```
                 p = fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\Desktop\\air.bmp", "rb");
                 int n = fread(head, sizeof(char), 100000, p);
```

Вот так выглядит картинка в hex редакторе 
[image: hex]

А вот так она записалась в массив [image: в массиве]
Очевидно , что некорректно , перевести такой массив в двоичную интерпретацию у меня не выйдет

Comment: не вижу причин, почему это могло бы быть невозможно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я пытался считывать в лоб (то есть открыл в HEX редакторе , посмотрел на сигнатуру BM , что за ASCII символы аналогичные 16-ричным стоят. Их и считывал в массив , чтобы потом в 2 код перевести. Но проблема : сигнатура BM не считывается корректно ,- завершающие нули считываются по середине(это я про сигнатуру) , а без неё не получится корректно вернуть обратно картинку )

Comment: если на win, то файл не забыл открыть в бинарном режиме?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, недавно я задавал вопрос , где выяснил,что он ничем не отличается от обычного https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795367/258486

Comment: Вообще там сказали нечто сильно другое, но каков вопрос таков и ответ... в любом случае без кода сказать в чём ты не прав не получится...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, изменил вопрос - посмотрите , пожалуйста

Comment: так, пока всё нормально, разве что обработку ошибок стоит сразу добавить — может у тебя файл не открылся... что за картинка я не понимаю, ну да ладно... что дальше с head'ом? для начала распечатай заголовок в hex'е в консоль... >> *завершающие нули считываются по середине(это я про сигнатуру) , а без неё не получится корректно вернуть обратно картинку )* << — что именно это описывает я тоже не понимаю...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, еще раз изменил - гляньте , если не сложно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75351/discussion-between-fat-zer-and-elvin).

Comment: А что такое head ? ощущение, что после чтения что то повредило сожержимое памяти. например вы выделили слишком большой массив в стеке и содержимое повредилось из за переполнения стека. любые большие блоки данных _необходимо_ выделять с помощью malloc.

Comment: "сигнатура BM не считывается корректно", но на скрине именно она и наличествует

Comment: Можно взять общее описание формата, например, в википедии: [BMP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP). Можно взять готовые определения структур из `Wingdi.h`. Просто выделяете память под структуры заголовка, читаете заголовок, дальше читаете байты изображения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно ознакомиться с общим описанием формата, например, в Википедии: [BMP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#BITMAPINFO).

Если упрощенно, в начале файла идут заголовки, потом уже сами бинарные данные:

> ### Общая структура
>
> Данные в формате BMP состоят из трёх основных блоков различного размера:
>
> 1. Заголовок из структуры BITMAPFILEHEADER и блока BITMAPINFO. Последний содержит:
>
>    - Информационные поля.
>    - Битовые маски для извлечения значений цветовых каналов (опциональные).
>    - Таблица цветов (опциональная).
> 2. Цветовой профиль (опциональный).
> 3. Пиксельные данные.

(из Википедии: [BMP - Общая структура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0))

По сути, чтобы добраться до описания пиксельных данных, нужно пропустить все заголовки.

Смотрим дальше, описание структуры [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#BITMAPFILEHEADER) (которая, собственно, идет с начала файла BMP):

- 2 байта - `bfType` - сигнатура формата. По сути - две буквы **BM**
- 4 байта - `bfSize` - размер файла в байтах
- 4 байта - поля `bfReserved1`, `bfReserved2` - зарезервировано (не используется, в 99% случаев будет заполнено нулями)
- 4 байта - `bfOffBits` - Положение пиксельных данных относительно начала данной структуры (в байтах).

Смотрим на ваш скриншот:

[image: BITMAPFILEHEADER]

В поле `bfOffBits` в файле записано число 0x36, и по смещению 0x36 от начала файла подряд идут значения FF (совпадение? не думаю). Тройка байт `FF FF FF` (8 бит * 3 = 24 бита на пиксель) как раз кодируют один пиксель белого цвета, т.е. это как раз и есть искомые пиксельные данные.

Что еще желательно знать? Во-первых при чтении нужно проверить, что картинка действительно имеет формат RGB с 24 битами на пиксель. Во-вторых нужно знать размер картинки.

Для этого нужно смотреть что идет следом за структурой. А следом идет структура [BITMAPINFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#BITMAPINFO), но сложность в том, что она может быть разных версий. Версия задается в первых четырех байтах. Самая древняя версия имела размер 12 байт, более новые от 40 байт и выше. Будем для простоты считать, что поддерживаем только новые форматы BMP, тем более что начало структуры BITMAPINFO у новых форматов совпадает.

Итак, в структурах `BITMAPINFO` новых форматах по порядку идут:

- 4 байта - `biSize` - размер структуры, нужен для определения формата структуры
- 4 байта - `biWidth` - ширина изображения
- 4 байта - `biHeight` - высота изображения
- 2 байта - `biPlanes` - количество "плоскостей" (в BMP не используется, а используется в курсорах и значках)
- 2 байта - `biBitCount` - количество бит на пиксель
- 4 байта - `biCompression` - использование сжатия (может использоваться, например, [RLE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) или JPEG сжатие)
- 4 байта - `biSizeImage` - размер пиксельных данных. В простейшем случае (без сжатия, например) будет равняться `biWidth*biHeight*biBitCount/8`.
- прочая информация...

Снова смотрим на скриншот:

[image: BITMAPINFO]

Отсюда получаем:

- Размер структуры `BITMAPINFO` - 0x28 (40 байт) - соответствует версии структуры `BITMAPINFOHEADER`
- Ширина изображения - `40 0B 00 00` = `0x0B << 8 | 0x40` = 2880 пикселей
- Высота изображения - `54 06 00 00` = `0x06 << 8 | 0x54` = 1620 пикселей
- `biPlanes` = 1
- `biBitCount` - 0x18 = 24 бит на пиксель
- `biCompression` - 0 (без сжатия)
- `biSizeImage` - `00 93 D5 00` = `0xD5 << 16 | 0x93 << 8 | 0` = 13996800, то же самое если посчитать `2880*1620*24/8 = 13996800`

Как с этим работать программно? Два варианта:

- Прописываем в программе жестко, по каким смещениям какие поля нужно прочитать, через `fseek` переходим по нужным смещениям, читаем данные, что нужно проверяем, что нужно читаем
- Подключаем заголовок `windows.h`, который автоматом подключает `wingdi.h`, объявляем переменные типов `BITMAPFILEHEADER` и `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, в них читаем данные от начала файла, потом из заголовка `BITMAPINFOHEADER` вытаскиваем поле `bfOffBits`, переходим по этому смещению с помощью `fseek`, читаем данные в заранее подготовленный массив пиксельных данных.

Псевдокод для второго случая:

```
#include <windows.h>

...

BITMAPFILEHEADER file_header;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmap_info;
FILE * file = fopen("file.bmp", "rb");

fread(file, &file_header, sizeof(file_header)); 
fread(file, &bitmap_info, sizeof(bifmap_info));
// Тут должна быть проверка, что прочитано именно столько байт, сколько и ожидалось, для простоты не показываю.

// Еще желательно добавить проверки, что файл именно нужного формата: есть сигнатура, файл нужной битности, без сжатия и т.д.

printf("width: %d", bitmap_info.biWidth);
printf("height: %d", bitmap_info.biHeight);
printf("bit count: %d", bitmap_info.biBitCount);

BYTE * bytes = (BYTE*)malloc(bitmap_info.biSizeImage);

fseek(file, file_header.bfOffBits);

// Собственно, читаем байты изображения
fread(file, bytes, bitmap_info.biSizeImage);

fclose(file);
```

Еще одна тонкость, если в поле `biHeight` лежит положительное число, то строки пикселей в файле записаны в обратном порядке (от нижней строки к верхней строке). Если отрицательное, то в прямом порядке.

Comment: ,А что значит глобальная палитра ? И почему у 24-рёх битного  bmp файла нет глобальной палитры ?

Comment: @Elvin, палитра нужна только если выбрана "битность" изображения с "ограниченным" набором цветов (например, 2, 4, 16, 256 цветов). В этом случае в палитре для каждого номера цвета задается его оттенок, а в пиксельном массиве для каждого пикселя указывается номер его цвета в палитре. Для 24-битной цветности нет смысла задавать палитру, потому что в каждом пикселе и так явно указан цвет.

Comment: ,почему подобная запись 00 93 D5 00 превращается в побитовые смещения и логические или ?

Comment: @Elvin, ну можно и так записать: `0xD5 * 256**2 + 0x93 * 256 + 0`, суть останется та же. Так (через "ёмкость" байта) может даже нагляднее. Ну как написал так написал. Сдвиги просто подчеркивают что байты состоят из бит, сдвиг на 16 бит например - это сдвиг на два байта. Ну а битовое или - это просто операция "объединения" для битов, примерно аналогичная сложению для "обычных" чисел. Когда складываемые биты между собой не пересекаются, то результаты битового или и сложения одинаковы.